# To Create a web solution Setup in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have created a web solution in visual studio 2010 ,i have also created a  setup project  in the same solution,I have linked the two solutions by adding  project output as content files. 
imagine my solution name is example.sln and i have setup name as setup10

I need to build it thru command prompt. 
I found in the net that i need to check the build option in configuration manager of the solution i did that.
I then used this command 
msbuild example.sln
it started to create setp10.vdproj
then it failed telling that setup10.vdproj doesn't exist.

I am not able to solve this problem from a day.
kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

vdproj files are not supported directly by msbuild  You'll have to build then by calling devenv.exe

You can add a build step to msbuild to build the vdproj with devenv.  See http://thepursuitofalife.com/how-to-build-vdproj-files-in-msbuild/ for more details.